# How to test a segue attached in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, testing, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I want to attach a `Show` segue to a property cell of a table view in storyboard. Now I want to test this binding is exists. i.e. I want to have a test that would fall if I delete the segue in the Interface Builder or changed the segue identifier.

From a user perspective, user taps on a cell of the table view and then this segue should be performed.

From testing perspective, I can swizzle the `prepare(for:sender:)` method the verify the performing of a segue, but I don't know how to trigger a "tap" programmatically.

I've tried `tableView.selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition)`, `cell.setSelected(_:animated:)` and those both didn't work.

1. How to programmatically trigger the segue added via InterfaceBuilder ?
2. Or is there any other way to test this segue binding?

---

## Update for further clarification

I know how to trigger a segue programmatically -- thus that is not what being asked here.

The segue triggering work is done behind the scene by storyboard and there is no segue triggering code in the production code (there is only a overriden `prepare(for:sender:)`). And the app work as intended. The problem here is I need a test to guarantee this behind-the-scene triggering always exists, that is: if someday I got drunk and mis-edited the storyboard to connect the original segue to somewhere irrelevant, there would be a test to go red and kick me in the ass.

Comment: `performSegue` would perform the segue programmatically

Comment: yes, but the thing I want to test is "a tap on the cell would trigger the segue",  not "what happens when the segue is triggered"

Comment: UI testing - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/09-ui_testing.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to test a segue that is wired up to the **view controller** instead of the table view cell.

In the app, I perform the segue when the cell is tapped. This is roughly equivalent to what you get if you wire up the segue to the table view cell.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showNextView", sender: nil)
}
```

This allows the segue to be tested as follows:

```
func testSegue() {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    // create the view controller that has the segue to be tested
    let viewController = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TableViewController") as! TableViewController

    // assuming the view controller does a Show segue, put it in a navigation controller
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)

    // this is needed or test fails!
    navigationController.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    // replace the root view controller with the navigation controller
    appDelegate.window!.rootViewController = navigationController

    // finally, select the row! this fires the segue
    viewController.tableView(viewController.tableView, didSelectRowAt: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))

    // assert something about the result of the segue
    XCTAssertTrue(navigationController.visibleViewController is SeguedViewController)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use this func : 

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOURIDENTIFIER" sender:self];`
It may help you test your segue.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question `I want to have a test that would fall if I delete the segue in the Interface Builder or changed the segue identifier`, I'm not testing the segue behavior, but the existence of segue binding

Comment: This is the correct approach, This method throws an Exception handling if there is no segue with the specified identifier.

Comment: What if there was a segue with correct identifier but it was connected to some irrelevant UI elements? This function call won't fail